# How do I create a virtual environment with Conda on Windows 11

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

I downloaded miniconda and tried using the `conda create -m gymenv`
but it kepps on saying

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> conda create -m gymenv
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Sosa Imagery\miniconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\Sosa Imagery\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" create -m gymenv'
```

Please what do I do? I'm working on a project and this has ben giving me issues

I was expecting a Virtual environment where I can install openai gym to be created

Comment: According to the docs, it's `conda create -n gymenv`, https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html